# proving that a sequence is basis

Tags: functional-analysis, schauder-basis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvlpu.png)
[image]
[image]

Q1 : In proof of part a) in proposition 8.1 from book "Ivan singer, Bases in Banach spaces I"
I don't know why he write that $$\displaystyle\sup_{1 \leq n < \infty} \|\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i\| \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle\sup_{1 \leq k \leq n} \|\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i x_i\|$$
where $A_1$ is the Banach space $\{ \{\alpha_n\} \subset K : \sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i x_i \text{ converges }\}$ endowed with the norm $\|\{\alpha_n\}\| = \displaystyle\sup_{1 \leq n \leq \infty} \|\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i\|$
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is waaaay tooo long...just to read the definitions! please be wayu more concise and ask *one* precise question, lest most people here won't even try to read all that...

Comment: I edited it. can you help me?

Comment: "$≤$" is true because the two expressions are actually equal. This may be a typo.